# OpenSSL client verification - Need client side validation requirements

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, x509certificate, x509

i have a C tcp client which as of now works with SSLV3

need guidance on what and i am missing and what i need to do extra in the client side

i am still not so clear on implementation and trying to read documentation and understand
request people to show some light 
(have cut many things from the orginal code)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "socketApp.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "logger.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <malloc.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define TCP_KEEPALIVE 0x2
fd_set readSet, actualReadSet;
static int xSocket,ySocket,zSocket;
static char debugBuf[200];
char str[4][20] = {"INVALID","x","y","z"};
char xLogPrint=0;

#define FAIL    -1
char CertFile[] = "SocketCert.pem";
char KeyFile[] = "SocketPrivateKey.pem"; //current no key implemetation is done
SSL_CTX *ctx;
int server;
static int sslStatus;
SSL *ssl;
SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void);

int setupSSL(int server){
    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = InitCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile);
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL ){   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_y(stderr);
        return -1;
    }else{
        sprintf(debugBuf,"Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG);
        setSSLContext(ssl,sslStatus);
        return 0;
    }
}

int LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )/* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    {
        ERR_print_errors_y(stderr);
        debug_log("Certificate Load error",TRACE_LOG);
        return -1;
    }
    //printf("Server certificates:\n");
   // line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    //printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
   /* if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_y(stderr);
        abort();
    }*/
    /* verify private key
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
        yrintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        printf("abort at SSL_CTX_check_private_key");
        abort();
    }*/
    debug_log("Certificate Load success",TRACE_LOG);
    return 0;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = SSLv3_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        //ERR_print_errors_y(stderr);
        debug_log("SSL context load failure",TRACE_LOG);
        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:creation Failed: %d %s\n",stderr,ERR_print_errors_y(stderr));
        debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG); 
        //abort();
        return ctx;
    }
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CertFile,NULL);
    return ctx;
}


int socketfdInit(void)
{
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    return 0;
}

int connectToServer(int server,int serverIP, int serverPort)
{
    long arg = 0;
    int *serverSock= NULL;
    int retVal, keepalive=5000,sockOpt=1;
    struct sockaddr_in localAddr, serverAddr;
    int valopt; 
    struct timeval tv;
    socklen_t opt_len; 
    int sock_err =0; 
    fd_set tempSet;
    sslStatus=getSSLEnableStatus();
    sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:x_SOCKET:sslStatus: %d \n",sslStatus);
    debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG);
    if ((*serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:%s_SOCKET:creation Failed: %d %s\n",str[server],errno,strerror(errno));
        debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG); 
        return -1;
    }

    if (sslStatus == 1){
            retVal=setupSSL(*serverSock);
            if (retVal != 0){
                return retVal;
            }
            else{
                FD_SET(*serverSock, &readSet);
                FD_SET(*serverSock, &actualReadSet);
                return 0;
            }
        }

}   

int SendToSock( int msgLen,char *msg)
{
    int i,numBytesSent;
    int sock_err =0; 
    int sock_errl = sizeof(sock_err);
    int serverSock = 0;

    if (sslStatus == 1){
        numBytesSent = SSL_write(ssl, msg,msgLen+2);
    }
    else{
        numBytesSent = send(serverSock, msg,msgLen+2, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    }

}
int ReceiveFromSock(char *msg,int Rxtimeout)
{

    // time val for select expiry
    struct timeval tv;
    int opt_len; // for querying getsocket opt -->value of length of result
    int sock_err=0; // placeholder integer where result is passed by getsockOpt
    int bytesRecvd=0;
    int selectRetVal;
    int tempBytesRecvd;
    int status;

    fd_set errSet ;
    int serverSock = 0;
    int len;
    char lenStr[3];
    if (sslStatus == 1){
                bytesRecvd = SSL_read(ssl, (char *)lenStr, 2);
                SSL_get_error(ssl,status);
                sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:x_SOCKET:recv: get error value %d",bytesRecvd);
                debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG);
            }else
                bytesRecvd = recv(serverSock, (char *)lenStr, 2, 0);    //receive the length in EBCDIC
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this do most of it: `SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);` and `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CertFile,NULL);`?  What errors are you getting?  What happens when you connect to a "snakeoil" (untrusted) cert?

Comment: @ebyrob :True this is working well but i just wanted to know what are the things i am missing.

Comment: If you're safe from MitM already (according to basic testing), then it's probably more a question of "what's in here that could bite me" than "what should I add".  For instance do you really want to add all algorithms?  `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();`  And why use SSLv3?  I believe even IIS can do TLS 1.2 by now...

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI,  Another way to solve this problem may be to run your C program under sslclient, which basically works similar to DJB's tcpclient, but with SSL - i.e. sslclient will spawn your program and open an SSL connection to the server, and pipe your program's stdout to the server, and pipe output from the server to your program's stdin.  The nice thing about doing it this way is that you can let sslclient to all the heavy lifting as far as negotiating SSL protocols with the server and doing the actual encryption, and you can focus on the core function of your program.  See http://www.superscript.com/ucspi-ssl/sslclient.html for more info.